# docpad: getting info on what exactly did got wrong

Tags: docpad

Docpad is throwing warnings at me all the time:

```
warning: Something went wrong while rendering: ...
```

I would love to know some more about what exactly went wrong. Are there any settings that I can tweak to make the output more helpful? In this particular case, the template is an `eco`file.

I have tried the `-d` option, but can't see that it helps.

I would love a special debug mode, where each layout, document, partial etc are rendered inside a border with the name of the file rendered. If the variables available inside the file could be serialized and shown in a popup or something, I would be thrilled. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That special mode sounds a lot like what [TraceGL](https://trace.gl/) will soon be able to offer. TraceGL seems amazing, but I can't seem to get it to work with DocPad yet.

For the meantime, do the [debugging instructions on the DocPad Website](http://docpad.org/docs/debug) help at all?

Comment: I tried to fiddle a little with the debug setting, but it didn't do me anything good in this case. I'm not that experienced with javascript - I can imagine that's the reason :-)

Comment: If you can provide the repo on github, I could do up a video where I debug it.

Comment: I think I solved the particular problem that I had, but next time I'm stuck, I would love to take your offering!